# How can I get just the directory name from a variable that includes a fully qualified filename in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

In powershell this variable is the path to the profile:  `$Profile`

On my system it equals:

```
  C:\Users\Warren\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
```

I would like to get just the path part:

```
  C:\Users\Warren\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\
```

In C# you would call `Path.GetDirectoryName`, so I guess I can call `[system.io.Path]::GetDirectoryName($fileName)` but I'm wondering if there's a builtin path manipulation system I should know about in PowerShell?

Is this what people do?

```
   [system.io.Path]::GetDirectoryName($Profile)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Split-Path` cmdlet:

```
Split-Path $PROFILE -Parent
```

Comment: `-Parent` can be omitted in this case.

Comment: Right I was just trying to show the full syntax, -parent is the default behavior